# Converting images to bytes array

Tags: java, android

I just want to ask, I have an application like Meme Generator.
So after taking a picture, the picture will be send to second activity,

My question is that, I'm having `Incompatible types` on Second Activity Like

> Required byte 
>   found java.lang.object

can you help me? or suggest another kind of method for doing this?

First Activity:

```
                    FileIOManager fiom = new FileIOManager(this);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    fiom.write("name",byteArray);
```

FileIOManager Class:

```
public class FileIOManager {

    private Context context;

    public FileIOManager(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void write(String filename, Object file) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(file);
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Object read(String filename) {
        Object object = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            object = is.readObject();
            is.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }

        return object;

    }
```

and lastly Second Activity

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    //byte[] byteArray = fiom.read("name");
    byte[] byteArray = fiom.read("name");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: i don't understand. in FileIOManager.read, why it return a Object, not byte[] type???try cast the Object to byte[] `(byte[])fiom.read("name")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope it will help...

```
public byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
  return byteArray;
}

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] bitmapBytes = bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
```